# How can i make memory allocated inside a function remain allocated when the function execution is finished?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I wrote a function in C++ that takes a string and a char as arguments, and return an array of strings where every array element is a word from the string.

```cpp
string* breakS(string s, const char* c){
    string::iterator it;
    int j=0, i = 1;
    for(it = s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
        if(*it == *c){
            i++;
        }
    }
    string* R = new string[i];
    for(it = s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
        if(*it != *c){
            R[j].push_back(*it);
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return R;
}
```

Since I never know how many words the input string will have, I had to dynamically allocate the array of strings.

This program runs fine, but when the function finishes its execution the memory allocated by  **string* R = new string[i]** will be deallocated, so I believe that if the string input is big enough the array of strings retuned by this program may be overwrited.

How can I make memory allocated inside a function remain allocated when the function execution is finished?

Comment: What led you to believe the mistaken notion that everything `new`ed inside a function gets automatically `delete`d, by itself, when the function returns? That is not the case.

Comment: can you use `std::vector` ?

Comment: your conclusion/interpretation is wrong (as Sam pointed out), but the pointer you return is basically useless because the caller has no way to know the size of the array it points to.

Comment: No, you are wrong, dynamically allocated memory does not get freed when you exit the function. That's why it's called dynamic allocation. You must be getting confused with automatically allocated memory, which does get released.

Comment: Why is the second argument a `cont char *`?  You are not traversing `c` in any way, so to me it could have been a simple `char`, not a pointer.  If you did that, then your question simply becomes :"how do I parse a delimited string?"

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is a bit off.

The memory for the `R` variable itself is indeed released when the function exits, as `R` is a local variable to `breakS()`.  But `R` is a pointer, and the memory that `R` is pointing at, the memory that is being allocated with `new[]`, will NOT be freed automatically when the function exits.  It becomes the caller's responsibility to `delete[]` that memory when done using it, eg:

```cpp
string* breakS(string s, char c, int &numWords){
    numWords = 0;
    string::iterator it;
    int i = 1;
    for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
        if (*it == c){
            ++i;
        }
    }
    string* R = new string[i];
    i = 0;
    for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
        if (*it != c){
            R[i].push_back(*it);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    numWords = i;
    return R;
}
```

```cpp
int numWords;
string *words = breakS("some,string,of,words", ',', numWords);
for (int i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {
    // use words[i] as needed...
}
delete[] words;
```

A better way to handle this memory management is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>

std::vector<string> breakS(string s, char c){
    string::iterator it;
    int i = 1;
    for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
        if (*it == c){
            ++i;
        }
    }
    std::vector<string> R(i);
    i = 0;
    for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
        if (*it != c){
            R[i].push_back(*it);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return R;
}
```

```cpp
std::vector<string> words = breakS("some,string,of,words", ',');
for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i){
    // use words[i] as needed...
}
```

Which can then be simplified further, as you don't need to pre-size a `std::vector` in order to add new elements to it, it grows dynamically as needed, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<string> breakS(string s, char c){
    std::vector<string> R;
    string::size_type start = 0, idx = s.find(c);
    while (idx != string::npos){
        R.push_back(s.substr(start, idx-start));
        start = idx + 1;
        idx = s.find(c, start);
    }
    if (start < s.size()){
        R.push_back(s.substr(start));
    }
    return R;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make memory allocated inside a function remain allocated when the function execution is finished?

Let me rephrase (so the answer is more catchy):

> What do I have to do to make sure the string array is not deallocated when the function returns?

Nothing!

Dynamic memory does not work that way. Unless you do call `delete []`, the memory gets never deallocated automatically (until your program terminates and all memory is released).

However, returning the pointer to the first element of the string array is rather useless for the caller, because they have no way to know the size of the array. Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead. It can be returned as value and avoids many problems that come with dynamic c-arrays.